# How can I restore my Perl environment and modules to a known state on Mac OS X?

Tags: perl, osx-lion

I am an old time Perl hacker but I have basically given up on my Mac because I usually can't install anything with [cpan](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPAN/scripts/cpan).

Something in the dependency list usually fails with meaningless (to me) errors. My Mac is new but has a long history copied over during upgrades from previous Macs for over 10 years.

Over the years I have tried to use `fink`, `MacPorts` and `homebrew` and I suspect by this time I have many incompatibilities.

Before I post my latest problem what I would really like to do is start clean with Perl as if I had a clean OSX-lion install. Is there any way to do this without wiping my disk and installing OSX from scratch?

Comment: belongs to: apple.stackexchange.com . The question is about the "OS X admin" and not about programming.

Answer (score 5):

None of the projects you mentioned installs into system directories. So, removing them from your current user environment should be as trivial as taking them out of your path, and removing references to them from your startup files (e.g., `.bashrc`, or if you added them to your "login items" etc).

After that, you'd be left with what the OS gives you. LEAVE THAT ALONE. Install [perlbrew](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/App:perlbrew) (so you can install multiple `perl`s and switch among them without disturbing the rest of the system) and [cpanm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/App::cpanminus) (cause it's more funner ;-) and take it from there.

Make sure to read the documentation for everything you use so you understand what they do and how they do it.

PS: If you did *force* any of [fink](https://www.finkproject.org/), [ports](https://www.macports.org/), or [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) trample on system directories for some reason, you did it wrong. If I were you, I would choose to install from scratch in such a case (but make sure to back up your documents first). I personally think even `/usr/local` as homebrew developers advocate is not a good idea, but if you did that, at least they give you an [uninstall script](https://gist.github.com/mxcl/1173223).

Comment: "Make sure to read the documentation for everything you use so you understand what they do and how they do it." As far as I can tell this would take several lifetimes and since most things are not completely documented I would still not understand them completely. This suggestion is so vague as to be useless.

Comment: I know how to remove things from my path but that doesn't fix anything. It merely hides it. As soon as I try to use one of the package tools again the problem will still be there. The question is how to erase all of them so I can cleanly start over with one or more of them.

Comment: Man, Sinan trying to help you. Your "This suggestion is so vague as to be useless." is ... no comment.

Comment: I do not understand your response: If you do not need the things you removed from your path, what is preventing you from deleting the directories containing them? The only situation in which you can't do that is if you forced stuff to be installed in system directories. When installing/updating packages via MacPorts, you need to use a shell where its `perl` is first on the path (as I think @jm666 pointed out.

Comment: If you want flexibility in changing the paths, maybe the 'environment modules' system would work well.  I've not tested it exensively, but I've set it on on my mac so I can turn off fink, ports, or homebrew at will.  I can get back to clean paths with 'module unload ports fink homebrew'

Answer (score 4):

OS X and Perl = pain a bit, when want many modules.

Problems:

- **macports** - default 5.12 optional 5.14. Unfortunately **many** macports has wrong dependencies, asking exactly 5.12 and when you have 5.14 running into problems Your default perl will be 5.14 and some packages will install and use 5.12 :(.
- **perlbrew** - very good and easy but here is a drawback. When you want install some packages with macports and what are depend on macport's perl - it's get installed. So you will get one macport's perl (what will works with installed package and perlbrew perl). And what is worse, your e.g. 5.14 perlbrew will not play correctly with macports (default 5.12). E.g. p5-GD, ImageMagick and many many others.
- **homebrew** - IMO, horrible. Stopped reading the doc when reach a section recommending **rm -rf /usr/local**. (of course, with all data, e.g. mysql). Maybe now it is better.
- fink, same problems as macports.

My solution:

simple using macports version for real development and perlbrew only for testing (but not with dependent binaries, like GD and so on). When want "perlbrew" sourcing its shell-start-files, otherwise not and using macports.

Another source of pain is - trying install macports version of perl modules first (because of consistency and dependency) and only when macports version is not exists, or need the newest cpan version - installing it with `cpanm`. CPAN version Extutils::Makemaker does not like macports version - and recompiling it all times when installing modules with `cpanm`.

Real pain. Macports badly need a new perl - maintenaier, who will clean up wrong dependencies and make the macports version of `cpanm` what will install cpan version of modules correctly as macport packages. Something has FreeBSD has years ago - cpan modules comes into BSDPAN bundles what are manageable with pkg_* commands.

So the result: I'm currently don't known any easy OS X perl usage. immediately when you want use some perl-dependent software you will must compile them itself (and sometimes they will not compile - so you need the patched version for OSX, so start uses macports or homebrew and ... pain.. ;(

As Sinan already told - any of those installations does not interfere with your system perl, but you probably started using cpan first with system perl and installed some modules into /Library..

IMO, you can live with it. Simply install macports and start using it. But if you want some perl-repair-installation - probably the better place to ask is at: https://apple.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: This question is not about what to use to upgrade perl. The question was how to get rid of what I have already installed. Keep in mind that the original version of fink and mac ports I have are probably over ten years old. The methodology of some of these tools has changed over time. I'm trying to figure out how to clear out all the clutter and start over. Then this advice might be useful.

Comment: As i told above - for the questions about partial restore of the perl to the "after-installation-state" - is probably the better place  http://apple.stackexchange.com/ . **It is not a programming question, but OS X admin question.** It is probably different in the Lion and SnowLeopard, because the difference in their installation method. Seems you haven't any alter installation TimeMachine backup, so the best way will be using Pacifist to reinstall only Perl form install media. (so only "/System/Library/Perl" and /usr/bin/perl*)